# Is there a way to run NUTCH with different configuration files?

Tags: solr, lucene, nutch

I was wondering if its possible to run the same NUTCH instance with different set of configuration files ? I can't see of any options in the arguments list to allow such thing.

I want to run NUTCH on only 1 computer and I don't want to duplicate the nutch instance.

Does anyone know of a easy way of doing this or do i need to modify the bin/nutch script myself to get it done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This nutch FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FAQ#How_can_I_force_fetcher_to_use_custom_nutch-config.3F) should be useful. The answer describes how to create your custom conf directory and have nutch pointing to it through the `$NUTCH_CONF_DIR` environment variable.

Comment: I have read that before and I  believe that it is for using the sub-directory only. I am looking for a way to be able to specify which configurations to use when i call bin/nutch. Unless I am missing someting.

Comment: @breakdown1986 I just tried it. It isn't just for subfolders, you can put the conf dir wherever you want and use the NUTCH_CONF_DIR to let nutch know where it is located. I guess that is what you're looking for, let me know if you need help!

Comment: Hi javanna, i am trying to use the same nutch instance to crawl with two different settings. For example, I need to crawl two different sites and index them separately using solr. I am trying to write a shell script to do this automatically. Therefore I need  2 sets of configuration files so in my shell script i can tell nutch to use those 2 different settings. Does that make sense ??

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood from your question. You can have two conf dirs with different names and use the NUTCH_CONF_DIR to let the nutch executable know which one to use. What am I missing?

Comment: I guess it was me understanding that wrong. Where do you have to set the NUTCH_CONF_DIR in ?

Comment: It's an environment variable. It depends on your operating system. On Linux `export NUTCH_CONF_DIR=/path/to/conf`

Comment: Yeah It worked. 

The only reason I needed to have different config files is to have seperate regex-urlfilter.txt for different tasks. With this way I am copying over some files that i dont need to. Can you suggest a better way of doing it ?

Comment: Actually i don't know. It could be a new question, but I'm not sure you can do better than now.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Unix symbolic links and change this link in your script. Like, if you have regex-urlfilter-conf_A.txt and regex-urlfilter-conf_B.txt. In your script, before starting nutch :

for conf A :

```
ln -sf $NUTCH_FOLDER/conf/regex-urlfilter-conf_A.txt $NUTCH_FOLDER/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt
```

for conf B :

```
ln -sf $NUTCH_FOLDER/conf/regex-urlfilter-conf_B.txt $NUTCH_FOLDER/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt
```